# Python 3.4 decode bytes

Tags: python, string, byte, decode

I am trying to write a file in python, and I can't find a way to decode a byte object before writing the file, basically, I am trying to decode this bytes string:

```
Les \xc3\x83\xc2\xa9vad\xc3\x83\xc2\xa9s
```

into this, which is the original text I'm trying to recover:

```
Les évadés
```

I tried using the .decode('utf-8') and encode('utf-8') but nothing seems to work...

I always get `Les Ã©vadÃ©s` as a result...
I am using python 3.4.3

Anyone can help?

Comment: Python3 uses utf8 as default encoding. From where are you getting that string?

Comment: What you're showing is utf-8 being interpreted as if it were latin-1. My guess is that Python is producing the correct output, but whatever you're printing it with is set to expect latin-1 rather than utf-8.

Comment: where did the string come from?

Comment: I'm guessing you're on Windows? Then don't use UTF-8, Windows uses different encodings by default.

Answer (score 3):

And if you want a Python 3 solution:

```
b = b'Les \xc3\x83\xc2\xa9vad\xc3\x83\xc2\xa9s'
u = b.decode('utf-8').encode('latin-1').decode('utf-8')
print(u)
# Les évadés
```

Answer (score -1):

What you need to do is to decode and then encode:

```
s = "Les \xc3\x83\xc2\xa9vad\xc3\x83\xc2\xa9s"
utf = s.decode('utf-8')
latin = utf.encode("latin-1","ignore")
print latin
```

--> Les évadés

Comment: `s` is a `str`, so you can't `decode` it on Python 3, nor is `encode`ing the proper final step to convert to `str`. And error handler of `"ignore"` is basically saying "throw my data on the floor, I don't care". I can see why someone down-voted. You wrote incorrect Python 2 code, that can't even run on Python 3.